# How to use InstanceMethod() to wrap a method returning an Object?

Tags: node.js, node-addon-api, n-api

Working on creating an add-on that will return an `Object` to the node environment.  Basing my work on [Atul Anand's introduction to N-API in C++](https://medium.com/@atulanand94/beginners-guide-to-writing-nodejs-addons-using-c-and-n-api-node-addon-api-9b3b718a9a7f), the methods of the class object are wrapped in `InstanceMethod()` to expose them; but that function wants a method that returns a `Napi::Value`.  I can't figure out the invocation to convert the C++ pointer into a `Value`; `Value::From(env, ptr)` errors (Visual C++ 2017) with "cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Napi::Value'".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that even as I was asking here, someone else was [asking](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/issues/484) at the Node-API-Addon github site.  The solution initially posted to the user's question was what I needed to get my code working.

In short (and obvious in retrospect): the C++ pointer is useless in JavaScript, the method needs to return a JavaScript object wrapping the C++ object.  The JS object is maintained within a `napi_ref` (`Napi::Reference`) and the reference's `Value()` is what gets returned from the access method.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use **napi_wrap** and **napi_unwrap** in your native code during cross boundary object access.
**napi_unwrap():** to retrieves a native instance that was previously wrapped in a JavaScript object
**napi_wrap()**: to wraps a native instance in a JavaScript object

The following URL is for n-api documentation Object Wrap, that has more detailed information about it.
https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html#n_api_object_wrap

The following github example has this usage
https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/tree/master/8_passing_wrapped/napi

Comment: Not so useful: If you['d read the link I posted, you'd see I am using the N-API C++ wrapper classes, which hide the `napi_XXX` API calls, and *that* is the problem I wanted to solve. Not really interested in having to dig deeper, but I had to anyway because N-API is so scantly documented.